# Update Indexer Specified List<T> Item while building another List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List and want to update certain items determined by their index while stuffing them into another list.

I have this class:

```
public class Offer
{
  public string LineId {get; set;}
}
```

I populate it in code prior to the section in question.

```
List<Offer> offersV2...snip...
```

Now I want to take specific items and put them into another list but first I need to update the LineId. So I've been trying variations of this:

```
var offersListX2 = new List<List<Offer>>()
{
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2[0].LineId = "1"},
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2[8].LineId = "13"} 
}
```

Intellisense (which is just using reflection so not always accurate) says I'm good to go but at compile time I get an error saying can't convert from Offer to string. So my List appears to be projecting the object prior to updating the property.

So I tried GetElement instead of using the indexer same error at compile.

```
var offersListX2 = new List<List<Offer>>()
{
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2.GetElement(0).LineId = "1"},
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2.GetElement(8).LineId = "13"} 
}
```

If I abstract out to a helper method like this it works fine.

```
var offersListX2 = new List<List<Offer>>()
{
   new List<Offer>() { MyHelperMethod(offersV2[0], "1"},
   new List<Offer>() { MyHelperMethod(offersV2[8], "13"} 
}
```

So my question is if I can do this in Linq / Lambda etc. eliminating the helper method.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea (which is why it isn't a coincidence that this is so hard for you; this is hard to do because you're not really doing things that the language wants to be encouraging).  Are you sure you don't want to be creating a new `Offer` that is based on the offer from the other list but with one different value, rather than mutating the offer?

Comment: Why don't you just use two lines, one updating data and one building a new list? The initializer syntax is not meant to have that kind of side effects, even if it would work you would confuse the next maintainer.

Comment: @Servy No. That was the other approach I had thought of but in reality I have numerous properties in the Offer class and just felt it was redundant to recreate so many properties just to change one.

Comment: @nvoigt I forgot to add that to my question. I had thought of doing it in two lines but couldn't figure out the syntax. That would be acceptable and I will update my question to include that option.

Answer (score 2):

I find that it helps to make code more clear if you make a clear separation between imperative code that has side-effects and more functional code that does data transformations. Here's what I'd suggest:

```
offersV2[0].LineId = "1";
offersV2[8].LineId = "13";

var offersListX2 = new List<List<Offer>>()
{
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2[0] },
   new List<Offer>() { offersV2[8] } 
};
```

LINQ could be useful if you're trying to make a list based on many of the values in `offersV2`, based on some criteria.

```
var offersListX2 = offersV2.Where(...).Select(o => new List<Offer> {o}).ToList();
```

But I wouldn't recommend it when you're just including two predefined values like this. And I should mention that the fact that you're accessing indexes with constant numbers and setting values with magic strings is a huge code smell. Should `offersV2` be a class rather than a list, perhaps? Or should this information be coming from some kind of collection? Think on it.

Comment: So perhaps the helper method is the proper solution...and my thought process was bad form. As you said the helper or seperate lines will provide clarity between side effects (like projecting the object) and functional code that does transformations.

Comment: @user1278561: I think the helper method is actually *hiding* the side effects, and I wouldn't recommend it at all. You may want to rethink the whole problem and question why you're creating side effects in the first place. I get the sense that there are a lot of improvements that could be made on a wider scale, but it's hard to understand the big picture based on the few lines of code you've provided.